Continuous function supported in $[2-\delta,2]$, satisfying integral of $f(x)\sqrt{4-x^2}$ equals $1$.
Fix $\delta >0$.
I want to show the existence of continuous function $f$, satisfying $supp(f) \subset [2-\delta, 2]$ and $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{2-\delta}^{2} f(x)\sqrt{4-x^2}\,\mathrm dx=1\;.$$
How do I prove this? Will mollifier be used?

Kou, what do have you tried in order to solve your problem?

Why can't $f$ just be a (perhaps large) constant? Or did you mean for the support to be compactly contained in $[2-\delta,2]$?

@Ian, I agree with you, it could be a constant.

@lan Sorry. I want the support of the function f to be contained in [2-δ, 2], but a constant function would be discontinuous at the end of the interval, so I am wondering what I should do.

You could literally put $f(x) = C\cdot\sqrt{4-x^2}$, integrate a typical integral, substitute the boundaries, and use what's left as a definition of $C$. The constant $C$ would depend on $\delta$, but since you've fixed it, it's not a big deal.

To start with, try $f(x)=g(x)\sqrt{\max(0,4-x^2)}$. That makes $f(2)=0$ and still continuous at $2$. Then you can craft $g(x)$ so that $g(2-\delta)=0$ as well

@Alex K Thank you very much! I was able to solve the problem.
